# Am I charged for creating and keeping AWS S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created two buckets back in 2018 but never removed them. Rest assured that they are empty buckets with no files at all.

I didn't see any fee charged, so I presume Amazon/AWS didn't charge for simply creating S3 buckets?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Answer (score 5):

S3 pricing is based on object storage, not buckets. You can read more about S3 pricing on the AWS S3 pricing page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, even though you're not charged for the bucket itself, [you can still incur some charges related to them](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-deleted-s3-charges/).

Answer (score 0):

There are six Amazon S3 cost components to consider when storing and managing your data—storage pricing, request and data retrieval pricing, data transfer and transfer acceleration pricing, data management and analytics pricing, replication pricing, and the price to process your data with S3 Object Lambda. For my details about the pricing model, check it out [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)